# Bitbucket: Conditionally add default reviewers based on the code that was changed?

Tags: git, pull-request, bitbucket-server

We would like to add our database guru to pull requests, but only if `.sql` files are present in the pull-request.

Ideally this would be achieved via a plugin or built-in support, but we're open to custom API integrations if necessary.

Answer (score 0):

While looking for the same, I found this:
https://marketplace.atlassian.com/apps/1211303/workzone-pullrequest-workflow?hosting=datacenter&tab=overview

Looks like you can do that, but if you are not in cloud this will cost you $$$

It is a plugin which allows you to automatically add reviewers based on changes detected in folders or files.
I have not tried it yet myself but I plan to.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference. Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.